# C# Multiple users Read/Write to database at the same time

Tags: c#, database

I want to connect a C# application with winform which I am planning to deploy to 600 users at my organization. multiple users need to connect and read/write to a network database file at the same time. what is the best way to achieve that?
is it possible doing that with excel/access/streamfile to txt or I have to do it in SQL?

Is it possible to find online some open-source code for this which can be manipulated?

Thank you,
Ori

Comment: SQL Server is a multi-user database. It's primarily intended to handle multiple simultaneous requests.

Comment: Who will manage concurrency? Database engine or _you_ in your code? Even in case of database with which strategy?  Hmmmm _"...I am planning to deploy to 600 users..."_. I'd wait little bit more...

Comment: You must think your way through. Begin with reading about sql transactions isolation level, and see what's the right way for you to go

Comment: "is it possible doing that with excel/access/streamfile to txt ?", yes.  Should you do it? **Definitely not**.  Go with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use a database for 600 users. Multiple handles to a text file with write access will become very complicated.

Databases are built for multiple users at the same time. You  could use Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL (Open Source) for example.